What is an example of a non-tight probability measure?
Billingsley (Convergence of Probability Measures, 1968) and van der Vaart and Wellner (Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes, 2023) discuss the concept of tight probability measures and use the concept to prove important weak convergence theorems in probability. A measure is tight over a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a compact set $K \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(K)>1-\epsilon$.
I believe that every real-valued random variable is tight under the usual topology of the real numbers, so I would like an example of a probability measure that is not tight. This is likely something in an infinite-dimensional space, like a function space, where some non-compact set has non-trivial measure.

how about the ones mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434857/is-probability-measure-always-tight and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963791/give-a-counterexample-of-the-compactness-property

There are some examples in chapter 41 of Fremlin's books, 418Xe and 419Xh are relevant

A simple example: An uncountable product of the open intervals $(0,1)$ with the direct product of Lebesgue measures on each factor $(0,1)$.

Every Suslin space is a Radon space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space#Radon_spaces and every space that matters in applications is Suslin, even function spaces like spaces of distributions $S'$, $D'$. That's why it's hard to construct examples of non-tight measures. More importantly, I think such examples are not interesting/useful.

I encountered the following statement in van der Vaart and Wellner: "A Gaussian process $X$ in $l^\infty(T)$ [where $T$ is an index set] is tight if and only if $(T, \rho_p)$ [where $\rho_p(s,t)=\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X(s)-X(t)\right|^p\right]^\frac{1}{\max(1,p)}$] is totally bounded and almost all sample paths $t\mapsto X(t,\omega)$ are uniformly $\rho_p$-continuous for some $p$ (and then for all $p$)." This may provide a roadmap for a counterexample. I have made two attempts that failed because the processes were not in $l^\infty$: Wiener process on $\mathbb{R}$ and iid Gaussians on $[0,1]$.
